# R programming language LOOPS

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

```
y <- vector()
i <- 5
while((2<3)<i){
y[i] <- "Hello World!"
i <- i-1 }
y
```

So I didn't understand how to while loop works when `while((2<3)<i)` is the case, `2<3` is true for all conditions and i end up with `TRUE<i`, what does this mean? Or am I thinking wrong?

I just didn't get how to condition of the while loop works, if I get that I believe I will work it out.

Also another question:

```
xxx <- function(vec){
    n <- length(vec)
}
for(i in 1:n){
      x <- vec[i]
       if (vec[i]<x){
               x <- vec[i]
 }
 } return(x)
```

This `xxx` function is suppose to output the minimum value of the function? okay i see but how?
when we enter the loop we first do x`<- vec[i]` without doing this we can't pass to the next command the if statement right? so since we do `x <- vec[i]` earlier if command won't work probably since `x==vec[i]` all the time.

Please help guys since iI have the exam tomorrow :(

Comment: I would suggest that you go over your code and carefully annotate what each line is doing. I would also suggest that you Google how to use while loops and how to define functions in R- there are so many great examples and explanations online, you really don't need someone to do it for you here. Lastly, you lack a clearly defined problem or question. Based on your post, I don't know what you are trying to accomplish with the `while` loop, and you confusingly ask why the `xxx` function does something that it doesn't do. Can you edit your post to demonstrate research effort and a clear problem?

Answer (score 2):

**1)** `?Comparison` says, referring to the two arguments of any comparison operator such as `<` :

> If the two arguments are atomic vectors of different types, one is
>   coerced to the type of the other, the (decreasing) order of precedence
>   being character, complex, numeric, integer, logical and raw.

so in this case we have one logical argument and one numeric argument so the the logical argument is coerced to numeric (where `FALSE` is converted to `0` and `TRUE` is converted to `1`).  Thus `(2<3)<5` is the same as `TRUE < 5` which is the same as `1 < 5` which is `TRUE`:

```
(2<3)<5
## [1] TRUE
```

**2)** For `xxx` you probably want this:

```
xxx <- function(vec) {
    x <- Inf
    for(i in seq_along(vec)) if (vec[i] < x) x <- vec[i]
    x
}
```

The first statement in the body assigns `Inf` to `x` In the second statement in the body `seq_along(vec)` is `1`, `2`, ..., `length(vec)` so the for loop iterates `i` over `1`, `2`, ..., `length(vec)` with each iteration replacing `x` with `vec[i]` if `vec[i]` is less than `x`.  Note that if `vec` has zero length then the loop is not run at all since `seq_along(vec)` has zero length.

Testing it out:

```
> xxx(1:3)
[1] 1
> xxx(3:1)
[1] 1
> xxx(numeric(0)) # zero length input
Inf
```

Of course R already has the `min` function which does the same thing.